# How do find a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, memory-leak-detector, vmmap

I have created an Application in MFC. After running my Application for 18 hours, the process reached 2.5 GB memory usage. I have tried VMMap to find out the memory leak. But it gives only high level data.

Is there any tool which can give me the memory leaks from dump file or is there a to use VMMap 
to find out the source of memory leak.

Comment: This question is off-topic as it's asking us for recommended tools, you can check out debugdiag and windbg, they are free, debugdiag is easier to use

Comment: If you are using MS Visual Studio and can get your application to shut down cleanly, you can try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Rational Purify](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/rational-purify-family) from IBM could help you out. (no relation)

I've used it before to good effect.